# How to animate group of images in winform application using VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, image, animation

I am trying to load bulk images and trying to put them as a slideshow and it's working fine.

Now I would like to have some effects like flip out,ease out effect and fade effect on those images when changing them without using any user control as I would like to do with the existing picturebox.Is it possible to do so?

If so can anyone point me to some resources.

As I have done googling and found some useful links and I am placing here that might helpful to someone.And all these have use seperate usercontrols to do, and I am not looking into that.

http://code.google.com/p/dot-net-transitions/

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/fluid_effect.aspx

Comment: The built-in picture box has no such capability. Your solution will require custom-drawing regardless what control you use (assuming you don't get a 3rd party product).

Comment: @john thanks for the info so that I can start using to create my own user control for this.

Comment: Moved to answer to allow closing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in picture box has no such capability. Your solution will require custom-drawing regardless what control you use (assuming you don't get a 3rd party product).